# Group of all upper triangular matrices and lower triangular invertible matrices are conjugates?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $X$ be set of all upper triangular matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Then does there exist $T\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $TxT^{-1}$ is a lower triangular matrix $\forall x\in X$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Take $T$ to be defined by
$$
T_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & i + j = n + 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$T$ is invertible with $T^{-1} = T$.